# Assert on missing fixture parameters in PyTest

Tags: python, pytest

In PyTest I want to make an `assert` that will fail when a parameterized fixture is missing a parameter.

I have a test I want to run against certain subclasses in a module. I have a parameterized fixture that lets me specify test data for each subclass.

```
def _fixure_params():
    return [
        (my_module.MyClassA, 'x'),
        (my_module.MyClassB, 'y'),
        (my_module.MyClassC, 'z')
    ]

@pytest.fixture(params=_fixture_params())
def my_fixture(request):
    ...

def test_my_subclass(my_fixture):
    ...
```

If a developer adds a new subclass but forgets to add an entry to the fixture parameters I want an assert to fail somewhere. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a fixture parameterized with the list of subclasses (using `inspect.getmembers()`), and then create a test that asserts that each fixture is in the list returned from `_fixure_params()`.

```
@pytest.fixture(params=inspect.getmembers(...))
def my_subclass(request):
    return request.param

def test_subclass_in_fixture_params(my_subclass):
    subclasses_in_fixture_params = set([t for t, _ in _fixure_params()])
    assert my_subclass in subclasses_in_fixture_params, "Missing fixture params."
```

This would be asserting on the fixture parameters, rather than on the fixtures themselves. Kind of clunky, but it works.